# Correct equation for Q learning

Tags: machine-learning, q-learning

I start learning Q learning algorithm. However, I can not understand which is the correct equation for q learning. I found different equation from different sources.

Source 1 [Reinforcement Learning with Q tables](https://itnext.io/reinforcement-learning-with-q-tables-5f11168862c8)

Source 2 [Q-learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-learning)

Source 3 [What Is Q-Learning: The Best Guide To Understand Q-Learning](https://www.simplilearn.com/tutorials/machine-learning-tutorial/what-is-q-learning)

I would like to know which one is the correct equation. If all are correct then how could I derive one from the other?